# Cannot reinitialise DataTable Error with columnFilter

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, datatables

I am trying to add Columnfilter to this piece of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#sampleOrderTable').DataTable( {
   dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
   processing: true,
    serverSide: false,
    ajax: {
        "url": '<?php echo base_url(); ?>welcome/datatable',
        "type": "POST"

    },
    "tableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": '<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/DataTables-1.10.4/extensions/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf'
    },
    "columns": [
        {
            "className":      'details-control',
            "orderable":      false,
            "data":           null,
            "defaultContent": ''
        },
        { "data": "RES_ID" },
        { "data": "PROP_NAME" },
        { "data": "RES_STATUS" },
        { "data": "RES_CHECK_IN" },
        { "data": "RES_CHECK_OUT" },
        { "data": "RES_N_ADULTS" },
        { "data": "RES_GUEST_FIRSTNAME" },
        { "data": "RES_GUEST_LASTNAME" },
        { "data": "BOOKING_SOURCE_LABEL" },
        { "data": "DATE_ADDED" },
        { "data": "IS_TRANSFER" },
        { "data": "IS_ARRIVED" },
    ],
    "order": [[1, 'asc']]

});
    $('#sampleOrderTable').dataTable({
     "bProcessing": true,
    }).columnFilter({
        aoColumns: [ 
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "date" },
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "text" },
            ]
    });
```

Tried to add the columnfilter before the end of the first DataTable but getting this error over and over again.. Does anybody know what Is wrong there? Cannot reinitialise DataTable Error

I tried to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#sampleOrderTable').DataTable( {
   dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
   processing: true,
    serverSide: false,
    ajax: {
        "url": '<?php echo base_url(); ?>welcome/datatable',
        "type": "POST"

    },
    "tableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": '<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/DataTables-1.10.4/extensions/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf'
    },
    "columns": [
        {
            "className":      'details-control',
            "orderable":      false,
            "data":           null,
            "defaultContent": ''
        },
        { "data": "RES_ID" },
        { "data": "PROP_NAME" },
        { "data": "RES_STATUS" },
        { "data": "RES_CHECK_IN" },
        { "data": "RES_CHECK_OUT" },
        { "data": "RES_N_ADULTS" },
        { "data": "RES_GUEST_FIRSTNAME" },
        { "data": "RES_GUEST_LASTNAME" },
        { "data": "BOOKING_SOURCE_LABEL" },
        { "data": "DATE_ADDED" },
        { "data": "IS_TRANSFER" },
        { "data": "IS_ARRIVED" },
    ],
    "order": [[1, 'asc']]

 .columnFilter({
            aoColumns: [ 
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "date" },
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "text" },

            ]

    });

});
```

But nothing happends on the page..

Comment: Hi Valery. Im not too familiar wifh DataTable, but I see a couple of problems:  in this line: `var table = $('#sampleOrderTable').DataTable({`  you use `DataTables` , but on the next line where you use it again you do this: `$('#sampleOrderTable').dataTable({` using `dataTables` . This should be case sensitive, which might give you some errors. However, the reason you are receiving that error is probably because you are initializing it twice. Why not place the `columnFilter` at the end of the first initialization?

Comment: Hi Diego! Good to see you around.. I wanted to include it in the first initializing but something is wrong with what I am doing, you can see the new code I edited

Comment: And by the way if i use DataTables syntax for both of the initializinions it doesn't work at all..

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#sampleOrderTable').DataTable({
        dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        processing: true,
        serverSide: false,
        ajax: {
            "url": '<?php echo base_url(); ?>welcome/datatable',
            "type": "POST"

        },
        "tableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": '<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/DataTables-1.10.4/extensions/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf'
        },
        "columns": [
            {
                "className": 'details-control',
                "orderable": false,
                "data": null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            {"data": "RES_ID"},
            {"data": "PROP_NAME"},
            {"data": "RES_STATUS"},
            {"data": "RES_CHECK_IN"},
            {"data": "RES_CHECK_OUT"},
            {"data": "RES_N_ADULTS"},
            {"data": "RES_GUEST_FIRSTNAME"},
            {"data": "RES_GUEST_LASTNAME"},
            {"data": "BOOKING_SOURCE_LABEL"},
            {"data": "DATE_ADDED"},
            {"data": "IS_TRANSFER"},
            {"data": "IS_ARRIVED"}
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    }).columnFilter({
        aoColumns: [
            {type: "text"},
            {type: "text"},
            {type: "text"},
            {type: "text"},
            {type: "date"},
            {type: "text"},
            {type: "text"},
            {type: "text"},
            {type: "text"},
            {type: "text"},
            {type: "text"},
            {type: "text"},
            {type: "text"}

        ]

    });

});
```

Comment: Hmm nothing happens at all using this, nothing is loaded

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get rid of the error finally using the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#sampleOrderTable').DataTable( {
   dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
   processing: true,
    serverSide: false,
    ajax: {
        "url": '<?php echo base_url(); ?>welcome/datatable',
        "type": "POST"

    },
    "tableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": '<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/DataTables-1.10.4/extensions/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf'
    },
    "columns": [
        {
            "className":      'details-control',
            "orderable":      false,
            "data":           null,
            "defaultContent": ''
        },
        { "data": "RES_ID" },
        { "data": "PROP_NAME" },
        { "data": "RES_STATUS" },
        { "data": "RES_CHECK_IN" },
        { "data": "RES_CHECK_OUT" },
        { "data": "RES_N_ADULTS" },
        { "data": "RES_GUEST_FIRSTNAME" },
        { "data": "RES_GUEST_LASTNAME" },
        { "data": "BOOKING_SOURCE_LABEL" },
        { "data": "DATE_ADDED" },
        { "data": "IS_TRANSFER" },
        { "data": "IS_ARRIVED" },
    ],
    "order": [[1, 'asc']]

});

    $('#sampleOrderTable').dataTable().columnFilter({
        aoColumns: [ 
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "date" },
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "text" },

            ]

    });
```

Not sure if the right way but it works now.

Comment: hmm, interesting. I'm just glad it worked. its weird to me. the next thing I was going to suggest was to do this: `table.columnFilter({  }`

Comment: I wanted to ask you, could you recommend me CRUD library for codeigniter?

Comment: I would use this one : http://www.grocerycrud.com/ However I have not used it myself as I usually create it from scratch

Comment: Yes, this what i was thinking.. grocerycrud is pretty good however if i setup bootstrap theme it takes about 15 seconds for the table to load.. not sure? perhps seperating tables in the SQL will help performance?

Comment: most definitely. I would always let SQL do the heavy work.